# PowerPoint animation issue: one name, picture appears, disappears, second name appears in the same place

Tags: vba, animation, powerpoint

I have been playing with animations in PowerPoint, but this relatively simple thing seems to be beyond my range. I want on the first (title) slide, one name with his details to appear below, then disappear on clicking (or pressing "n") and then another name should appear in the same place (where the first name was) with his details. If this can be managed with animations, fine, otherwise I am open to use VBA macros also.

If this is too easy, I would like to add a symbol/picture (.bmp) for the first person to appear in the middle of the slide, which would disappear with that name, and then with the second name appearing, the second picture/symbol (.jpg) should appear in the middle of the slide. I will be glad if someone can show me how to do this. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is the wrong place to ask "how do I use this software" type questions. Superuser.com would be a better place. And yes, what you describe can be done with animations. You can configure several animations to enter/exit at the same time. That is done in the animation pane.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll need to use macros. I can't picture *exactly* what you want the presentation to look like, but this sounds quite easy. I'll give you an instruction list, as clear as I can make it.

1. Place the item(s) *(the placeholders containing the name and details, as well as the pictures)* you want to animate into your presentation, in the positions you want.
2. Select the item(s) you want to appear first, and choose a suitable entrance effect from the `Add animation` menu.
3. Bring up the animations pane from the animations ribbon, if you haven't already done so. If you wanted multiple items to appear at once, then set any extra items to `with previous`.
4. Do the same with an exit effect (on the same item(s)). They should be after the entrance animations on the animation pane. The first (from the exit animations) should be `on click`; the rest should be `with previous`.
5. Select the next item(s) you want to appear, and choose an entrance effect. Instead of `on click`, choose `after previous`.
6. Test to see if everything works the way you want it to.

I've done my best to make this as clear as possible, but if there was an inaccuracy, or something unclear anywhere, then please let me know.